# Maven OSGI netbeans api unresolve dependency

Tags: maven, netbeans, osgi

In maven osgi bundle has the following netbeans

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>org-openide-dialogs</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE721</version>
</dependency>
```

And MANIFEST.MF was generated automatically, and I have the following unresolved package

Bundle : at.ac.ait:TargetFileGenerator:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT has unresolved package dependencies:
    org.apache.commons.io;version="[2.1.0,3.0.0)"
    org.openide.util

What can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the Netbeans API package requires Apache Commons, so need to include that package in your pom.xml file. [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/) has multiple versions of Apache Commons listed. Here is the dependency information for [version 2.1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.directory.studio|org.apache.commons.io|2.1|jar):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
<artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
```

Comment: thank you, but now I still get unresolved package for netbeans.api 
Actually, that's my real problem, I can not resolved netbeans api package for my project

Bundle : at.ac.ait:TargetFileGenerator:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT has unresolved package dependencies: 
org.openide.util

Comment: What repositories are in your pom file? Your dependencies may require a additional Maven repository.

Comment: <repository>
            <id>netbeans</id>
            <name>Netbenas MVN</name>
            <url>http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

Comment: I think , i must added embed dependency , but how ?

Comment: See the [maven](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) site for reference on how to add repositories to a pom file.